# How to convert unix timestamp into Date

Tags: sql, hibernate, date, datetime

I am trying to convert Unix time stamp into date

```
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    final String startdate = Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong(requestVO.getStartDate().toString()))
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT-4"))
            .format(formatter);

        final String enddate = Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong(requestVO.getEndDate().toString()))
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT-4"))
                .format(formatter);
```

above is what I have tried for the format of date Mentioned in DateTimeFormatter and requestVO.getStartDate() is giving Date type value.I am applying the startDate and endDate in sql query Like below

```
and ceo.erx_date between '"+startdate+"' and '"+enddate+"'
```

No compilation errors getting But, giving number format exception.

Comment: share the sample timestamp and exception you are getting

Comment: 1544954090 unix timeStamp and I am expecting 2018-12-16 15:24:50

Comment: @phanikumar You actually do not need the "Unix timestamp" (count from epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z). Just convert from `Date` to `Instant`.

Answer (score 0):

If `requestVo.getStartDate()` returns a `Date` object, your error is here:

```
Long.parseLong(requestVo.getStartDate())
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)) says, `Long.parseLong(String)` throws

> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable long.

Try this:

```
Long.parseLong(requestVo.getStartDate().getTime())
```

In every case two things:

1. Take care from `NullPointerException`: check if your date is null or not
2. Use preparedStatement and not string concatenation when write e query in Java

There are at least two reasons to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`:

1. They are faster then simple `Statement`: because `Statement` are compiled and execute every time, but `PreparedStatment` are compiled once
2. In case of `PreparedStatement` you are safe from the point of view of [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate                               // The terrible `java.util.Date` class is the legacy way to represent a moment in UTC.
.toInstant()                                 // `Instant` is modern way to represent a moment in UTC.
.atZone(                                     // Adjust from UTC to some time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "America/Martinique" )        // Specify the time zone you had in mind for an offset of four hours behind UTC. 
)                                            // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.format(                                     // Generate text representing the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object's content.
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME    // A predefined formatter per ISO 8601 that omits any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC.
)
.replace(
    "T" ,                                    // Standard ISO 8601 formats use a `T` between the date and time-of-day portions.
    " " 
)                                            // Returns a `String`.
```

## `java.util.Date::toInstant`

> requestVO.getStartDate() is giving Date type value.

You are working too hard.

Convert the terrible `Date` class object to its modern replacement, `Instant`. Notice how the legacy classes were given **new methods for conversion** to/from the modern *java.time* classes. Look for `to…` & `from…` methods on the old classes. In this case, [`Date::toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toInstant()).

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

## Zone versus offset

> .atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT-4"))

Nope, `-4` is not a time zone. That is an offset.

An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian.

A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone carries a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Asia/Kolkata` or `Pacific/Auckland`.

Better to use a time zone than a mere offset. For one thing, you may be wrong about the offset. By using an time zone, *java.time* will determine the offset in effect at your intended moment.

### Zone for offset of four hours behind UTC

Perhaps by -4 you have in mind a time zone such as `America/Martinique`, `America/Aruba`, or `America/Puerto_Rico`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Puerto_Rico" ) ;
```

### `Instant` + `ZoneId` ➡ `ZonedDateTime`

Apply that `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Generating text

Produce a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, wisely extended to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

But you wanted a format similar to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but without the `T` in the middle and with no indicator of offset/zone. I do not recommend reporting a moment without representing the time zone or offset. But if you insist:

```
String output = 
        zdt
        .format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
        .replace( "T" , " " ) 
;
```